# Access Properties of a new Stream in Esper

Tags: esper, epl

I'm starting a new stream by using the statement:

```
insert into middleLayerStream 
    select id, 'response' as constraint 
    from[...]
```

Afterwards I'm starting a SELECT-query to the middleLayerStream. In die update-function of my middleLayerStream I want to print out the properties of the stream.

This is my update function:

```
public class MiddleLayerListener implement UpdateListener {
   public void update(EventBean[] newEvents, EventBean[] oldEvents) {
      EventBeant[] event = newEvents[0];
      System.out.println(event.getUnderlying());
   }
}
```

When the update-function is called, I don't get the properties but this statement instead:

```
{a=MapEventBean eventType=com.espertech.esper.event.map.MapEventType@52500920, b=MapEventBean eventType=com.espertech.esper.event.map.MapEventType@52500920}
```

How do I get access to the properties?

I just found out, that event is not a simple EventBean but a MapEventBean. Maybe it's because two different types of events (but with the same properties) are inserted into the stream. But how can i handle a MapEventBean and get the properties out of it?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Your post is incorrect. What you have cut&pasted is the output of System.out.println(event) and not System.out.println(event.getUnderlying()).

Comment: That is exactly the output I get when I call event.getUnderlying(). And I have no idea why, because usually .getUnderlying() would return a list of the properties but it doesn't

Comment: On second look yes event properties can themselves be EventBean instances

Comment: And how do I get access on the properties of the Eventbeans?

Comment: updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The EventBean interface offers a "get" method that returns an event property value by name.

```
public void update(EventBean[] newEvents, EventBean[] oldEvents){
  for (EventBean event : newEvents) {
    System.out.println(event.get("id"));
  }
}
```

You left off the "from" in your post so it wasn't possible to see what was selected. I assume that you have a pattern in the "from" such as "a=A -> b=B".

In the case of a pattern returning a nested event `event.get("a.id")` or `event.get("a")` or `event.getFragment("a")` or `select a.id as id from [...]` would do.

Comment: Yes, I am using this in my other listeners and it's working totally fine, but when I do so in this listener, I just don't get any output. Nothing happens.

Comment: Whats does "nothing happens" mean...?

Comment: No error is occurring and the engine just keeps on going..

Comment: When the listener throws an exception, and since the runtime invokes the listener, make sure you have logging or code your listener so it doesn't have an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it..
In my SELECT Query that ist starting the update function of MiddleLayerListener I selected * like

```
SELECT * from pattern[every a=.... -> b=...]
```

So of course there a both events in a MapEventBean (a and b).
By specifying the SELECT Query like:

```
SELECT a.id as id from pattern...
```

In now have only the wanted properties in my stream and can access them as normal.

Wow.. that took me a whole day of desperation :D

Thank your very much for your help :)

Comment: Reading the docs may help. The first example is in 7.2.2. Patterns in EPL